Error in 'loadNamespace ! there is no package called "cardx"
Anyone knows how to interpret this error message. Have not made any changes.
processing file: TEMP4NY. Rmd Error in 'loadNamespace
! there is no package called "cardx" Backtrace:
1. rmarkdown: : render (... )
2. knitr:: knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
3. knitr:: :process_file(text, output)
6. knitr::: process-group (group)
7. knitr::: call_block(x)
14. base: : withRestarts (... )
15. base (local) withRestartList (expr, restarts)
16. base (local) withoneRestart(withRestartList(expr, restarts [-nr]),
17. base (local) docall (restartShandler, restartargs)
19. evaluate (local) fun(base:: quote(*<pckgNtFE>*))
Quitting from lines 121-131 [unnamed-chunk-4] (TEMP4NY. Rmd)
Execution halted
esc
1

g

It seems quite obvious from the error message that you need to install the package called cardx.

Try running install.packages("cardx") at the R console.
